# How i can get all pixels for all objects in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I have image with separate objects, which have one color.

example image:

[image: example]

I want to get all the pixels from each object. I use Python and CV2. But I do not know how to do it.

example that i want to get:

- object1 : [(x1,y1), (x2,y2) ... (xn1,yn1)] where n1 - count all pixels in object1
- object2 : [(x1,y1), (x2,y2) ... (xn2,yn2)] where n2 - count all pixels in object2
- ...
- objectm : [(x1,y1), (x2,y2) ... (xnm,ynm)] where nm - count all pixels in objectm

**UPD:** This can be done with cv2.connectedComponents(). See this [connected component labeling in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441893/connected-component-labeling-in-python). Thanks [beaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56817279/how-i-can-get-all-pixels-for-all-objects-in-opencv#comment100189958_56817279)

Comment: What is the expected output in the given context?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441893/connected-component-labeling-in-python

Answer (score 0):

considering that the img is open in 'img'
you can use immg[i,j] to return values of blue red green eg

```
>>img[12,12]
[143,144,255] // this is what is returned [blue green red]
```

so you can use something like

```
rows = img.shape[0]
cols = img.shape[1]
for (i in range(0,rows)):
    for (j in range(0,cols)):
        bgr=img[i,j]
    #now use if condition and match brg values with color you wnana detect then append the pair i,j in the a list if the condition matcches
```

Comment: This is not what I expected.  because your algorithm does not divide the image into separate objects