# How can I separate objects in a binary image?

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image, image-thresholding, binary-image

I have a binary image that I create in scikit-image like so:

```
img = image_to_process  

from skimage.filters import threshold_li
thresh = threshold_li(img)
thresh_image = grayscale > thresh
```

On the resulting *thresh_image* (binary), I want to run a further segmentation step that separates the masked objects.

However I only find segmentation methods that run on grayscale (e.g. `skimage.segmentation.watershed`) , but not on binary images. Do I understand this correctly, and if so, do you know of a way to separate objects in a binary image?

Thanks!

Comment: please add the `image_to_process` to your question to form the [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Objects in a binary image have the same value everywhere, so how you want to separate those objects any further? For binary images you can use morphology operators like open, close, dilate, erode...

Comment: @Phil **labeling connected components**, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46442154), might be the answer to your question.

Comment: Hi! @Bilal, I think this answer would work for me. Thank you! And as for the MWE, unfortunately I am not able to share the image publicly as I work with medical images. Sorry!

Comment: @Sembei - Maybe segmentation is the wrong term, I just need a way to separate objects from one another in a binary image. I will have a look at the binary morphology operators. Thanks!

Comment: If the objects are not touching each other, then you need to label connected components. Check this link https://scipy-lectures.org/packages/scikit-image/auto_examples/plot_labels.html  If the objects are touching by a small region you can separate them using the `opening` morphology operator https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [`skimage.measure.label`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label) on the binary image to separate the different objects.