# how to extract a particular region of interest from an mri image(not manually) when same intensities of other unimportant are also present?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, medical-imaging

I want to extract the **endotracheal region** from the `MRI` of the Sagittal plane of the neck image, but after applying image processing techniques like **thresholding, contour detection and binary masking**,

I could find that there are other **undesired regions** as well which are being extracted along with the required region of interest.

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread('sam_mri01.jpg')
cv.imshow('pre1',img)

image_contours = np.zeros((img.shape[1],
                           img.shape[0], 1),
                          np.uint8)

binary_img = np.zeros((img.shape[1],
                         img.shape[0], 1),
                        np.uint8)

for channel in range(img.shape[2]):
    ret, thresh_img = cv.threshold(img[:, :, channel],
                               25, 255,
                                     cv.THRESH_BINARY)
    cv.imshow('pre3', thresh_img)
    contours = cv.findContours(thresh_img, 1, 1)[0]
    cv.drawContours(image_contours,
                    contours, -1,
                    (255,255,255), 1)
    cv.imshow('pre4',image_contours)

contours = cv.findContours(image_contours, cv.RETR_LIST,
                           cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]

cv.drawContours(binary_img, [max(contours, key = cv.contourArea)],
                -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)
    
cv.imshow('result', binary_img)
cv.imwrite('result.jpg',binary_img) 
cv.waitKey(0)
```

The image:

[image: image of side view of neck(mri)]

the result obtained:

[image: result obtained].

I want only the particular tube-like **endotracheal channel** to be extracted or differentiated. the other regions in black need to be eliminated from the result and this has to be done automatically for any image of this type so that I don't need to set different parameters for different images.
The region of interest is the black coloured channel which is the endotracheal region:

[image: the black coloured channel which is the endotracheal region]

Comment: that CT has vignetting. that's weird. CT images usually come in Hounsfield units (-1000 to ~+3000), which correspond to physical quantities, which means these images should have no vignetting. see if you can get a better picture, preferably one that isn't a "picture" but medical data. -- you might need AI for this. distinguishing one black tube from other black regions needs some intelligence. low level image processing has little promise.

Comment: @smkd I suggest you inverse the image and use this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46442154), then if you count the pixels the desired region is the second-largest one (assuming your ROI is connected region).